# Подтянуть цену при совпадении названия товара

Tags: excel

В общем-то суть такая - нужно в Excel сделать своего рода запрос с существующей базы данных (Лист 1) в оформленный лист для распечатки (Лист 2, он же бланк "Прайс-лист для клиента" можно так назвать). Необходимо такое условие чтобы проверялось совпадает ли имя товара с набранным (допустим это столбец A в обоих Листах), и по соответствию имени в столбце B указывалась цена этого товара. В 1 листе база данных с наименованием товара в столбце А, цена в столбце B. Необходимо чтобы отображало в Лист 2 цену введенного товара.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Это легко делается при помощи функции ВПР.

Вот диалоговое окно данной функции:

[image: окно ВПР]

**Как использовать функцию ВПР.**

```
=ВПР(B2;C2:E7,3,ИСТИНА)
```

Первый аргумент (часть данных, которая обеспечивает работу функции) — это искомое значение. Это может быть ссылка на ячейку или конкретное значение, например «Карандаш желтый» или «Принтер лазерный». Второй аргумент — это диапазон ячеек, который, на ваш взгляд, содержит искомое значение. В нашем примере это диапазон C2–C7. Третий аргумент — это столбец в диапазоне ячеек, содержащий значение, которое нужно найти.

Четвертый аргумент необязателен. Можно ввести ИСТИНА или ЛОЖЬ. Если ввести ИСТИНА или оставить аргумент пустым, функция возвращает приблизительное совпадение значения, указанного в качестве первого аргумента. Если ввести ЛОЖЬ, функция найдет совпадение со значением, указанным в качестве первого аргумента. Другими словами, чтобы обеспечить дополнительную гибкость, оставьте четвертый аргумент пустым или введите значение ИСТИНА.

В этом примере показано, как работает функция. Если ввести значение в ячейку B2 (первый аргумент), функция ВПР выполняет поиск в ячейках C2–E7 (второй аргумент) и возвращает наиболее точное приблизительное совпадение из третьего столбца в диапазоне — столбца E (третий аргумент).

[image: пример]

Четвертый аргумент пустой, поэтому функция возвращает приблизительное совпадение. Иначе потребуется ввести одно из значений в столбец C или D, чтобы получить какой-либо результат.

Подробнее смотрите [Краткий справочник: функция ВПР](https://support.office.com/ru-RU/article/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%A0-b18f0fd2-7aa0-48f3-86f6-97e4c6841a5c)

А также - [Поиск значений с помощью функций ВПР](https://support.office.com/ru-RU/article/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%A0-%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%A1-%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%97-68297403-7C3C-4150-9E3C-4D348188976B)

Answer (score 1):

Для решения поставленной задачи, связать наименование Товара на `Листе 2` с `Ценой`на `Листе 1`, используем функцию MS Excel `ВПР()`.

1. Создаем `Лист 1` (База данных продуктов) со списком товаров (столбец `Товар`) и ценой (столбец `Цена`). Заполняем ячейки значениями Товаров и Цен.

Обязательными и необходимыми условиями для  корректной работы функции `ВПР()`являются: столбец `Товар`первый в списке и сортировка значений в нём в алфавитном порядке.

Ограничения: корректно функция `ВПР()` не будет работать для одинаковых товаров с разными ценами. Например:

Чай 122,00;

Чай 170,00.

[image: <code>Лист 1</code> (База данных продуктов)]

2. Создаем `Лист 2` (Прай-лист) со столбцами `Товар` и `Цена`.

[image: <code>Лист 2</code> (Прайс-лист)]

3. Связываем значение вносимых товаров с ценами, размещенными на `Листе 1`, с помощью функции `ВПР()` через наименование товаров.

Функция `ВПР()` вызывается следующим образом:

- первый аргумент - `Искомое_значение`, что мы ищем на `Листе 1`. В нашем случае `А4`;
- второй аргумент - `Таблица`, где мы ищем, на каком листе и в каком диапазоне. В нашем случае `Лист1!$A$2:$B$9`. Обратить внимание на абсолютные ссылки при задании диапазона `$A$2:$B$9`для исключения изменения диапазона поиска при копировании ячеек с формулами;
- третий аргумент - Номер_столбца, номер столбца из которого будет возвращаться значение в случае совпадения Искомого_значения. В нашем случае `2`. Если будет найдено значение, то будет возвращено значение ячейки 2-го столбца, если нет , то значение `#Н/Д`;
- четвертый аргумент - Интервальный_просмотр, логическое значение, определяющее точность поиска по Искомому_значению. `ЛОЖЬ` - точное совпадение, `ИСТИНА` - приближенное.

[image: Связываем товар с ценами через функцию <code>ВПР()</code>]

4. На `Листе 2` тиражируем ячейку с формулой `ВПР()` в столбце `Цена`ниже. При вводе значение в столбец `Товар` при совпадении наименования со значением товара на `Листе 1` функция `ВПР()` возвращает значение цены из столбца `Цена` либо значение `#Н/Д`.

Результат минимум достигнут.

5. Для скрытия значения `#Н/Д` при отсутствии еще введенных товаров и вывод уведомления об отсутствии товара на `Листе 1` дополняем функцию `ВПР()` следующими условиями и функциями: `ЕСЛИ()`, `ЕНД()`, `ЕПУСТО()`. Финальная редакция функции: `=ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(A4);"";ЕСЛИ(ЕНД(ВПР(A4;Лист1!$A$2:$B$9;2;ЛОЖЬ));"Нет продукта в списке цен";ВПР(A4;Лист1!$A$2:$B$9;2;ЛОЖЬ)))`

[image: Финальная функция]

Comment: =ЕСЛИ(A4="";"";ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(A4;Лист1!$A$2:$B$9;2;);"Нет продукта в списке цен")) - формула для версий после Excel-2003